# Javascript: localStorage paralyzes if-statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, local-storage

Made a boolean variable "*disableReplaceDate*", used in if-statements. Have to save the variable somehow because the page reloads and I need to use it to "check a status" sort of, so it doesn't return to default every time the page reloads.

Then, to save myself a lot of time and trouble, because I can't send them in the URL as parameters(it's occupied already by a complicated java file which manipulates it all and I'm no good at java at all), I decided to use window.localStorage setItem, getItem and removeItem etc., so basically

```
 var disableReplaceDate = false;
 window.localStorage.setItem("dRD", false);
 disableReplaceDate = window.localStorage.getItem("dRD");
```

But now the if-statement, which looked as follows:

```
 if(disableReplaceDate == true){/*do some stuff*/}
```

didn't work anymore! But then when I changed it to

```
 if(disableReplaceDate){/*do some stuff*/}
```

It starts working suddenly.

And if that wasn't uncanny enough, it won't do this for all if-statements using the variable, I tried changing them to (!disableReplaceDate) and such, but it doesn't make them work.

Why is this? And how do I solve it?

Comment: `getItem` return a string : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem

Comment: As you can see in the documentation, the value that is stored is supposed to be a string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem. JavaScript will convert it to a string automatically if it isn't one.

Comment: Ah ok, is there a better option for booleans then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) only stores strings. And `"false"` evaluates as `true` in a context where a boolean is needed (for example a `if` statement).

You should change

```
disableReplaceDate = window.localStorage.getItem("dRD");
```

to

```
disableReplaceDate = window.localStorage.getItem("dRD") === "true";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think because the type of your variable is "string" see this

```
typeof(disableReplaceDate)
```

The output will be `string`

I think you need to test this way `if(disableReplaceDate === "false")`